# Unity Inventory System Not Functioning Properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inventory

I have an AddItem method, this method takes items and adds them to the list.

```
public void AddItem(string itemName1, int amount)
    {
        Item existingItem = inventory.Find(item => item.itemName == itemName1);
        Debug.Log("existing item: "+ existingItem);
        if (existingItem != null)
        {
            existingItem.itemAmount += amount;
        }
        else
        {
            Item newItem = new Item();
            newItem.itemName = itemName1;
            newItem.itemAmount = amount;
            inventory.Add(newItem);
            itemInInventoryCounter++;
        }
    }
```

And I have an OnTriggerEnter2D method, which takes the objects that the player collides with, and sends them to the AddItem method with appropriate parameters.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Item"))
        {     
            Item collisionItem = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Item>();

            string itemName = collisionItem.itemName;
            int itemAmount = collisionItem.itemAmount;                
            if (inventory.itemInInventoryCounter < inventory.maxItemInInvetory)
            {
                inventory.RefreshInventoryItems(itemName, itemAmount);
                inventory.AddItem(itemName, itemAmount);
                Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("envanter dolu");
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue is that even if the item already exists, it always appears as empty. In other words, it never increases its amount; it always adds it as a new item.

I checked the list, and items are being added to the list. I did it as follows.

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            inventory.ShowInventory();
        }

    }

public void ShowInventory()
    {
        foreach (Item item in inventory)
        {
            Debug.Log(item.itemName + ": " + item.itemAmount);
        }
    }
```

Upon further examination, I've noticed that the items are not being added to the list properly. Although items are being added, they appear as "None(item)" in the Unity window. What does this signify? If they haven't been added, why I can see them on console window.

```
[System.Serializable]

public class Item : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string itemName;
    public int itemAmount;
    public SpriteRenderer itemSprite;

    public List<Sprite> inventory = new List<Sprite>();

    public SpriteDatas spriteDatas;

    public TextMeshPro itemAmountText;

    
    private void Start()
    {
        itemAmountText.SetText(itemAmount.ToString());
        itemSprite.sprite = GetSprite(itemName);
    }

    public Sprite GetSprite(string itemName)
    {
        switch (itemName)
        {
            default:
            case "Sword": return spriteDatas.spritesList[0];
            case "HealthPotion": return spriteDatas.spritesList[1];
            case "ManaPotion": return spriteDatas.spritesList[2];
            case "Coin": return spriteDatas.spritesList[3];
            case "MedKit": return spriteDatas.spritesList[4];
        }
    }
}
```

```
public void RefreshInventoryItems(string itemName, int itemAmount)
    {     
        if (itemInInventoryCounter <= maxItemInInvetory)
        {
            float itemsSlotCellSize = 110f;
            RectTransform itemSlotRectTransform = Instantiate(itemSlotTemplate, itemSlotContainer).GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            itemSlotRectTransform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            itemSlotRectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x * itemsSlotCellSize, y * itemsSlotCellSize);
            Image image = itemSlotRectTransform.Find("SlotItemPicture").GetComponent<Image>();       
            image.sprite = item.GetSprite(itemName);
            TextMeshProUGUI uiText = itemSlotRectTransform.Find("amountText").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
            uiText.SetText(itemAmount.ToString());

            x++;

            if (x > 3)
            {
                x = 0;
                y--;
            }
        }
    }

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Item item;
    public List<Item> inventory = new List<Item>();

    public Transform itemSlotTemplate;
    public Transform itemSlotContainer;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    public int maxItemInInvetory;
    public int itemInInventoryCounter = 0;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            RemoveItem("Coin",76);
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        maxItemInInvetory = 3;
    }

    public void AddItem(string itemName1, int amount)
    {
        Item existingItem = inventory.Find(item => item.itemName == itemName1);

        Debug.Log("existing item: "+ existingItem);
        if (existingItem != null)
        {
            existingItem.itemAmount += amount;
        }
        else
        {
            Item newItem = new Item();
            newItem.itemName = itemName1;
            newItem.itemAmount = amount;
            inventory.Add(newItem);
            Debug.Log("burada");
            itemInInventoryCounter++;
        }
    }

    public void RemoveItem(string itemName, int amount)
    {
        //burada sağ tıkladığımız nesneye göre envanterden çıkartıp dünyada spawnlayacak. 
        Item existingItem = inventory.Find(item => item.itemName == itemName);

        if (existingItem != null)
        {
            existingItem.itemAmount -= amount;
            if (existingItem.itemAmount <= 0)
            {
                inventory.Remove(existingItem);
                itemInInventoryCounter--;
            }
        }
    }

    public void RefreshInventoryItems(string itemName, int itemAmount)
    {     
        if (itemInInventoryCounter <= maxItemInInvetory)
        {
            float itemsSlotCellSize = 110f;
            RectTransform itemSlotRectTransform = Instantiate(itemSlotTemplate, itemSlotContainer).GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            itemSlotRectTransform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            itemSlotRectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x * itemsSlotCellSize, y * itemsSlotCellSize);
            Image image = itemSlotRectTransform.Find("SlotItemPicture").GetComponent<Image>();       
            image.sprite = item.GetSprite(itemName);
            TextMeshProUGUI uiText = itemSlotRectTransform.Find("amountText").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
            uiText.SetText(itemAmount.ToString());

            x++;

            if (x > 3)
            {
                x = 0;
                y--;
            }
        }
    }

    public void ShowInventory()
    {
        foreach (Item item in inventory)
        {
            Debug.Log(item.itemName + ": " + item.itemAmount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not related to your issue but note that `if (inventory.itemInInventoryCounter < inventory.maxItemInInvetory)` imho is at the wrong place here ;) This would stop you from collecting more items of an already known item type if your inventory is full .. you rather wan to have that check after checking if such item type already exist and only ignore if a new item type would need to be added ;)

Comment: what does `inventory.RefreshInventoryItems(itemName, itemAmount);`

Comment: and could you show you implementation of `Item`? maybe using `new` on it is not valid (e.g. if it is `MonoBehaviour`)?

Comment: If it is always creating a new instance of the item then that means that `existingItem` is null in the `AddItem()` method, which would imply your `inventory.Find()` method isn't working correctly. Could you post the implementation of your inventory class?

Comment: your main issue is `Item` being a `MonoBehaviour` and you are creating instance via `new` ... it is possible yes, but not valid in Unity .. you should see warnings about that in the console

Comment: also .. you call `RefreshInventoryItems` which updates the UI .. and only then you add the item to the inventory .. which does the check for whether to add a new slot or just increase the count? Shouldn't it rather go the other way round?

Comment: @derHugo is right - the big problem is `Item` extends `MonoBehaviour`. Classes that extend Unity classes (like `MonoBehaviour`, `ScriptableObject`, etc) have their own equality override, which makes checking if an object is null a bit weird (sometimes `x == null` will be true, even though it's not really null). You should make `Item` not extend `MonoBehaviour`, or if you really need to keep it a `MonoBehaviour` you should create `Item`s by using `AddComponent()` instead of `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the issue(s) now!

- From this line

  ```
  Item collisionItem = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Item>();
  ```

  we can see that `Item` is a `MonoBehaviour`!

  You can not create instances of a `MonoBehaviour` using `new`! - Well you can, bu it will be an invalid broken instance!

  => What you should do instead is use a different type for the item definition itself and for the component you can interact with.

  I would probably

  - go with a `ScriptableObject` for the item definitions - here you can reference all textures, define the name (e.g. name of the SO itself), etc.
  - For the component you collide with reference that `ScriptableObject` so that

    - it initializes its visuals according to the referenced item definition
    - it provides that ScriptableObject reference to your `OnTriggerEnter2D` so it can either use it as key directly or its name
    - additionally this component has an `public int Amount` for how many of that item to add
  - Then finally in your `inventory` you do **neither** store the component **nor** the `ScriptableObject` item definitions but instead rather have a dedicated plain `Serializable` type that only holds an amount and the underlying `ScripableObject` reference (in order to use it as the lookup key)

    The inventory could even be a `Dictionary`
- You first call `RefreshInventoryItems` which UI-wise **always** instantiate a new slot regardless of whether you already have such an item!

  After that you do the `AddItem` which does the check whether to add a new item or increase the counter

  => You rather want to do this in the opposite order and call the `RefreshInventoryItems` after you either added a new item (=> spawn a new UI) or increased the amount (=> only update existing UI)
- And finally as mentioned a minor one but the check for

  ```
  if (inventory.itemInInventoryCounter < inventory.maxItemInInvetory)
  ```

  would prevent you from collecting any of the already known item types as soon as all slots are occupied.

  => I think you only want to check for the `maxItemInInvetory` when adding a **new unknown** item type. So that you can only have a certain maximum amount of different item types but can still keep collecting additional ones of those

  Unless of course your intention is actually the above mentioned behavior in which case you can ignore this point ;)

Comment: If the elements are not being added correctly, how can I view the items within the list correctly when I use the ShowInventory() function? I tried creating a ScriptableObject, but it's still not functioning properly.

Comment: @erdem.61 the `RefreshInventoryItems` should keep track of all the UI items it ever created and then accordingly only add new ones if needed, and either delete ones that are not needed anymore or only deactivate them and re-purpose them the next time (aka object pooling) ... but yeah before coming to the UI part I would first focus on actually getting the correct content into your list (using [debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html))